# Download a file and redirect...or alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, download

Users fill out a form.  With a valid form, they click to download a file.  I would like to be able to redirect them to another page (e.g., `page2.html`) AND initiate a download.

I can't initiate download on `page2.html` because most browsers will flag security warnings if a download link isn't directly clicked on.

How is something like this accomplished using javascript or jquery?  Obviously the following doesn't work but it's meant for illustrative purposes:

```
document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function(){
     window.location = "/download.exe";
     window.location = "/page2.html";
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a link to the file and `onclick` to trigger "go to the next page shortly".

```
<script>
function thanks() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.location.pathname = "page2.html";
    }, 1000);
}
</script>

<a href="file.exe" onclick="thanks()">Download now!</a>
```

Comment: Okay!  That works for IE at least.  On FF, Chrome, and Safari, users don't have enough time to click on the "Allow" field.  But as you said in your comment above, I may have to live with it.  Possibly use this for my IE users.

Comment: Do they just close the "download" prompt when it tries to go to something else?  Weird.

Comment: Yea the download prompt goes away (except on IE).

Comment: How about if you add `target="_blank"`?

Answer (score 3):

You can initiate the download on page 2 by having `page2.html` "change" its location (to your download URL) once the page is loaded:

```
$(function ()
{
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        window.location.pathname = '/download.exe';
    }, 5000); // download the file in 5 seconds
});
```

I'm pretty sure (though not 100%) that won't trigger a security warning.

Comment: I tested this on Safari 5, Chrome 8, FF 3.6, and IE7, IE8.  For Internet Explorer the download behavior is different (than if you directly click on a download link).  On IE, message "To help protect your security..." whereas if you click directly it just opens up a file save.

Comment: @Emile: that's going to be the case whatever you do; it's normal behaviour which you'll have to live with. That's why sites often have "if this download doesn't start, click here" and things like that. I believe it's normal to initiate the download when the page loads, too (without any additional issues).

Comment: a side-note....and this is very strange, but on Safari 5 for Chrome, window.location.pathname produces unexpected results...Safari tries to "search" your pathname with the default search engine.

Comment: @Emile: did you mean "Safari 5 **or** Chrome?" Any chance you can post a repro link?

Comment: @Matt! Ha! oops...meant Safari 5 for Windows 7.  I don't have a server version to show, but you can attach the window.location.pathname to an onclick event.

Comment: @Emile: ah ok, don't worry about it - I'm not running Windows 7.