# PHP Headers - Content & Location

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download a file and redirect…or alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373440/download-a-file-and-redirect-or-alternative)

Basically, we have a PHP file which outputs a file type using PHP headers.

We want it to work like this:

User clicks link, page opens, download prompt comes up and then the page that prompted the download (the main php page) redirects to another page...

How can I go about doing this? I want it to only redirect once the download prompt has been delivered to the user.

So.. sort of a thank you page.

Can this be done like so:

```
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: public', false);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: '.$type);
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
/* sleep for say 3 seconds.. */
header('Location: thankyou.php');
exit();
```

This code was purely written as an example, but how can we create something like this?

So the download prompt pops up, wait say 3 seconds, and then direct the origin page to a thank you page.

Comment: why not to go to one of zillions such download pages and see how it works?

Comment: What is a zillions such download page?

Comment: Pages of the same functionality. Like one on download.com or zillions similar sites.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP headers are output all at once (save for chunked sending, though I'm a bit hazy on whether HTTP allows that for headers).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373440/download-a-file-and-redirect-or-alternative) looks to be similar.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking something along these lines and doing it on the origin page but I didn't know weather it was possible or not via PHP.

Comment: @Latox: By definition, HTTP does not support that, that's pretty agnostic to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

header('Location: thankyou.php');

Will kill your download,

If you sleep you stop every thing and the browser wont receive the file it will just redirect to thank-you.php