# Java Servlet - Download and Forward to a page

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to send a download and then forward to a page. but once the download completes the forward doesn't happen.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ there's nothing wrong in the code.

Comment: How are you sending the download. Are you using `Content-Disposition" : "attachment; filename=...");`?

Answer (score 2):

That's normal behavior. A file download will write the content of the file into the response and close the response stream, and a forward will try to write new content on the already closed response, resulting in nothing new being written in the response.

Solution:

In your client, use JavaScript to fire the file download, and also fire a request to the page you want to forward.

Client code adapted from here: [Download a file and redirect...or alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4373440/1065197)

```html
<script>
function thanks() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.location.pathname = "another.jsp";
    }, 1000);
}
</script>

<a href="${request.contextPath}/yourServlet?file=foo.dat" onclick="thanks()">Download now!</a>
```