# Yii2: refresh() not working after sending response content

Tags: yii2

I have a `ActiveForm` which I use to get some data from and when I click the send button it will run the model (in this case a csv file generator) but the refresh is not working, when I remove the method it will refresh.

After some testing it seems that `fputcsv()` will stop the script, so that everything that comes after this will not run.

**view**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new Export();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $fields = Yii::$app->request->post('Export');

        \backend\models\Export::generate();//this prevents the refresh

        Yii::$app->session->setFlash();

        return $this->refresh();
    } else {
        return $this->render('index' , ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

**model**

```
static public function generate() 
{
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    $data = [array comes here];
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");
    fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));

    foreach ( $data as $line ) {
        fputcsv($fp , $line , ';' );
    }

    stream_get_contents($fp);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to start a download and refresh the page? Take a look into sample.csv with a text editor. I guess you find there what you expect (or an error 'Header have been already sent...'). You could solve it via JS. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4373955/57091).

Comment: Yes i create a csv file, download it and then I want to refresh te page . No errors in the csv file.

Comment: is that your complete function `generate()` ?

Comment: The headers direct the browser to put all following data into the file sample.csv. So any HTML would go into it as well. Not sure if this is really required for you. Better keep things simple and just start the download. Why should the page be reloaded? Note that `$this->refresh()` also send headers. ...btw: What should `stream_get_contents($fp);` do? `Yii::$app->session->setFlash();` without parameters? Please provide proper code...

Comment: the reload is to reset the form, and to trigger the flash.

Comment: umm why dont you create a separate action for download and call it via ajax?

Answer (score 2):

`Controller::refresh()` uses `Location` header to reload page. Since headers need to precede the content, you cannot add new header after content was sent. Your `Export::generate()` method sends content, so you cannot add any header after that, thus `$this->refresh()` do not work.

Prior to Yii 2.0.14 there was a bug and framework simply ignored that you're trying to send header after content has been send. If you upgrade Yii, you should get "nice" Exception in this case.

---

If you're trying to display nice page after downloading file, your approach is incorrect. You can't really return file and then redirect to different page. You should first display nice HTML page and inside of it redirect user to download page (for example by using `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />` in head or creating hidden form and submitting it by JavaScript). After downloading the file user will stay at this nice page, so from UX perspective everything should be OK.