# PHP Force download prompts "This type of files can harm the device" in android chrome

Tags: php, android, force-download

We are trying to force download an .apk file when users reach our website using the below script

```
$path   = "../../".$_GET['file'];  
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['file'] );   
@readfile($path);
```

Whenever we reach the site and download starts, the following error of "This file can harm your device pops out" in android chrome only. But the same file, when we try to download it by typing in url address bar, it downloads without any warning message.

Any solutions to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That sounds like a security feature to me and I highly doubt you can disable it. Users manually typing in the URL in the address bar usually know what they're typing in there, but simply clicking on a wrong link on a website and having it download the user may not know what it is which would explain the different behavior.

Comment: I Understand mike, Is there a possibility where i could submit a form which initiates the php force download and at the same time redirect to another page simultaneously.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373440/download-a-file-and-redirect-or-alternative

Comment: Well facing another problem. Now the same script is not downloading the file. It is popping a error saying download failed due to unknown error.